# Prevent nodes from collapsing when selecting a node in Highcharts treegraph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization

I am using the treegraph type in Highcharts to visualize a phylogenetic language tree. When I click on a node, the default behavior seems to be collapsing or expanding its child nodes. I'd like to prevent this collapse/expand behavior and just register the click event.

I've gone through the Highcharts API documentation, but couldn't find a direct solution to prevent this behavior.

Here's a JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/jmqs64ug/70/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        spacingBottom: 30,
        marginRight: 120
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Phylogenetic language tree'
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'treegraph',
            allowDrillToNode: false,
            keys: ['parent', 'id', 'level'],
            clip: false,
            allowPointSelect: false,
            collapseButton: {
                enabled: true
            },
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log(event.point.id)
                    /* console.log(event.point.linkToParent) */
                    console.log(event.point.parent)
                    event.preventDefault()
                }
            },
            data: [
                [undefined, 'Proto Indo-European'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Balto-Slavic'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Germanic'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Celtic'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Italic'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Hellenic'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Anatolian'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Indo-Iranian'],
                ['Proto Indo-European', 'Tocharian'],
                ['Indo-Iranian', 'Dardic'],
                ['Indo-Iranian', 'Indic'],
                ['Indo-Iranian', 'Iranian'],
                ['Iranian', 'Old Persian'],
                ['Old Persian', 'Middle Persian'],
                ['Indic', 'Sanskrit'],
                ['Italic', 'Osco-Umbrian'],
                ['Italic', 'Latino-Faliscan'],
                ['Latino-Faliscan', 'Latin'],
     
            ],
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 6,
                fillColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 3
            },
            dataLabels: {
                align: 'left',
                pointFormat: '{point.id}',
                style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    textOutline: '3px #ffffff',
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
                },
                x: 24,
                crop: false,
                overflow: 'none'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Is there a way to stop nodes from collapsing/expanding upon selection, and just capture the click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Highcharts to achieve this:

```
 Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.seriesTypes.treegraph.prototype, 'click', function(proceed) {
  this.points.forEach(point => {
    point.toggleCollapse = function() {};
  });
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ubskjeg2/

**Docs:**
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

you can add for each data toggleCollapse = () =>{} to prevent it collapsed.
Example:

```
data: [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "test",
    parent: "20",
    toggleCollapse: ()=>{}
  }
]
```